# Cargar Spinner en Kotlin desde base de datos MySQL

Tags: mysql, android, kotlin

Como puedo cargar un spinner obteniendo datos de la base de datos en Kotlin. El siguiente código que es lo que estoy utilizando ahora me está cargando los datos utilizando un string-array desde el frontend, pero no desde la base de datos que es lo que necesito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Cual es la tabla y que estructura tiene? ¿Tienes implementado DAOs para obtener los datos de la base datos?

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es muy ambigua para poder ayudarte, ¿Que base de datos estás usando? Local o remota a travez de una api. Si es local, ¿Estás usando jetpack Room o estás usando SQLite?. Si quieres ayuda por este canal me temo a que deberás ser mas específico